# Input Japanese characters into CSV file (C#)

Tags: c#

I want to write Japanese strings (”設定"　　”HELLO”  "設定") as a record into CSV file.

I tried to do with this code but displayed incorrectly:

```
StreamWriter sw_CSV = new StreamWriter(CSvFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
sw_CSV.WriteLine("設定,HELLO,設定");
sw_CSV.Close();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the encoding to UTF-8

```
StreamWriter sw_CSV = new StreamWriter(CSvFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine, you just need to set encoding then you're opening file..

here is an example (I'm using OpenOffice here):
[alt text http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/1299/japanesecsv.jpg](http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/1299/japanesecsv.jpg)